# Spring:Connect Sql server from spring boot service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I  have rest  crud service  which  will  help  me make  post and  get requests  and  receive  respopnses from sql server , inside  my  application.properties  i use  similar data:

```
server.port=9004
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/1433;databaseName=test1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2014Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto =ddl-auto
```

AND   HERE  IS  MY  POM:

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>    

        </dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

when  i  run  this  as a java  project  i  alway  got  this  error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field: private
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters;
>   nested exception is

and:

> with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Error
>   creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory
>   method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]:
>   Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is

what  should  i  change  inside  my  pom  or properties  file  to  make  my  program  work?

Answer (score 9):

SQL Server dependency is deprecated, use following to interact with SQL Server

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

follow links for more information

[Configuring Spring Boot for Microsoft SQL Server](https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-spring-boot-for-microsoft-sql-server)

[Open sourcing the Microsoft JDBC Driver and Maven support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2016/11/17/open-source-jdbc-maven/)

Answer (score 6):

Since it is a REST app, need to add the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
       <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
       <version>4.0</version>
     </dependency>
```

Add also connection properties in config (`application.properties` by default):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=springbootdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=replace_value
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

Try that one and see if you can build/run the project.

Comment: first  of  all  thank  you for  your  reply  but  unfortanetly  it  doesn't work i mean  i can't start  my service now  i  have this error : org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Comment: will i need  to  add  persistence xml  or another configuration file  to meca database  connection more  convenient and accaptable  for  spring boot  application?

Comment: Yes, need to add the persistence config. See updated answer. Also see this link for reference: https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-microsoft-sql-server/

Comment: persistence.xml  insiede src/main/resource/META-INF

Comment: and   now  i have this  errors  :Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate

Comment: when  i  try  to connect remote sql server , perheps  it  is  mistake that  i  use spring dependecy  for embeded database?

Comment: Can you start from scratch by create a new project in `start.spring.io` with `web` and `jpa` as dependencies. Then add the `sqljdbc4` dependency in the pom file? Updated code above to include this dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Change your url parameter to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test1
```

Port number must be preceded by a colon(":"), not slash("/").