# spring boot configuration with MS SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server 2016 from spring boot application. SQL server is configured using **windows authentication**.

Following are the configuration

> application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://K877DTRV:1433;databaseName=testdb;integratedSecurity=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.initialize=true
```

> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

java version is 1.8.spring boot version is 2.0.3.RELEASE

I am getting the below error while starting the tomcat

> Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Should I do any additional configurations?

Note: I am using Windows Authentication.

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: You can check this link for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522338/springconnect-sql-server-from-spring-boot-service

Comment: I have went through those. Didn't match with my situation

Comment: Or this might help you: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/datasource-configuration/

Comment: No..I think i am missing something in windows authentication.please help me with that.Note:I am using mssql-jdbc dependency

Comment: Your dependency is fine. Could you paste the error you got? And would you mind to explain about windows authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a version to the pom entry for mssql-jdbc worked like a charm

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>6.4.0.jre8</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</dependency>
```